# Distorted Page in Internet Explorer Where Perfect in Chrome

Tags: html, cross-browser

I have a website which is located at http://maxflix.com/.

The website works perfect in Chrome and in IE at some extent but few pages of the pages are getting distorted in IE (please test "login" and "my account" page).

I am stuck with this problem and can't figure out the solution.

Can someone help me? I will really appreciate.

UPDATED:

Links:

1. Chrome Perfect
   http://i53.tinypic.com/r8cahi.png
2. IE (Correct Pages)
   http://i51.tinypic.com/kd0bgi.png
3. IE (Error Pages)
   http://i51.tinypic.com/kd0bgi.png

Comment: *(please test "login" and "my account" page).* Please post pictures of the differences, for starters. You'll probably get more answers that way. :)

Comment: your IE Correct Pages and Error Pages point to the same picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem anyway by changing a PHP code from:

```
<td>
<?php
if (tep_session_is_registered('customer_id'))
{
?>
<a href="shopping_cart.php"><div width="97" height="81" src="images_3/HEADER_TOP_15_02.gif"></div></a>
<?php    
}
else 
{
?>
<a href="create_account.php"><img width="97" height="81" src="images_3/HEADER_TOP_15.gif"></div></a>
<?php
}
?>
</td>
```

to:

```
<?php
if (tep_session_is_registered('customer_id'))
{
?>
<td width="97" height="81" background="images_3/HEADER_TOP_15_02.gif">
<a href="shopping_cart.php"><div width="97" height="81" style="width: 97px; height: 81px; cursor: pointer;"></div></a>
</td>
<?php    
}
else 
{
?>
<td width="97" height="81" background="images_3/HEADER_TOP_15.gif">
<a href="create_account.php"><div width="97" height="81" style="width: 97px; height: 81px; cursor: pointer;"></div></a>
</td>
<?php
}
?>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Validate your html and css for those lists of errors that need fixing. However, IE is not a modern browser and we all struggle getting it to work like any others.

Comment: the website is built in PHP. Are you sure I can still validate it? and How?

Comment: Simply copy and paste the URL to the page you want to validate in the text box here: http://validator.w3.org/. This will do the magic for you :-)

Comment: @JamWaffles - that validates HTML. This validates CSS: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/  @Umair Ashraf - It never matters what language you develop in. Only the HTML and CSS output matters for validation.

Comment: ah I got it. You mean me to validate the resultant HTML

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PNG images with transparency this issue can occur.  Internet Explorer doesn't support transparency on .png images

Answer (score -1):

Start out with a reset.css stylesheet. It's probably due to IE's built in formatting for margins and padding.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/